# Multiple Google Authentication scopes in .NET Core depending on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a web based app. This app allows users to sign up/in using Google Auth as per this code in Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["CliSecret"];
    ...
});
```

This all works nicely with the out-of-the-box Identity system so I can register users.

However, I also want users to be able to 'connect' to other Google services with separate accounts after the sign up in a separate area of the site.

For example, I might want a user to connect their AdWords account. 
They will authenticate with Google via a non-Identity flow and the relevant info (token, refresh token etc) will be stored independantly in the db (i.e it won't store a 'User' in the `AspNetUSers` table).

**Can I change the authentication scope in the controller before I make my initial call to google?**

It'd be nice to utilize the same Authentication service but with some extra scope in this case. Is that possible?

Alternatively, have *another* Google section in Startup.cs...maybe like:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["CliSecret"];
    googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords"); //*** THIS IS THE EXTRA SCOPE NEEDED ***
    ...
});
```

Comment: You will need multiple client Ids for that, like you suggested.

Comment: Ah - so I can't use the same client ID with adjusted scope configuration based on the situation? Also, if I use different client id's with Google Auth - how do i select the one I want?

Comment: You specify the clientId you want to use when you connect.

Comment: Scopes are granted for the application. To request additional scopes, the user has to reauthorize the app. The entire point is that your app should be up front about the scopes it may use, even if they aren't applicable to every user or every situation.

Comment: Cheers Chris. I’ve actually gone this route. The app requests the same things all over, I just manage the different uses of the scope in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem, our Identity Provider should be able to login users of defferent clients with different Google account

We decided to add multiple Google areas as you suggested. The main point here is that each area (which defines some google account) uses unique cookie scheme.

When we create login URL, we get google account needed for that client, get it's cookie scheme and create correct URL for Google Authenticate button

code example:

```
public static class AuthenticationBuilderGoogleAdder
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddGoogleAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder authenticationBuilder, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        // create IThirdPartyProvidersProvider realization with GetByProviderCode method
        var authThirdPartyProvidersProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<IThirdPartyProvidersProvider>();
        var googleProviders = authThirdPartyProvidersProvider.GetByProviderCode("google");

        googleProviders.ForEach(p =>
        {
            authenticationBuilder = authenticationBuilder.AddGoogle(p.CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.ClientId = p.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = p.ClientSecret;
            });
        });

        return authenticationBuilder;
    }
}
```

register it as

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogleAuth(services)
```

We call services.BuildServiceProvider() in order to create another container with services which were already registered in DI, in order to get Google accounts with different cookie schemas from the DB